# MS ACCESS: Insert into sharepoint list or local table, cannot join on memo, OLE or hyperlink object

Tags: sql, ms-access, sharepoint, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I have the error 'cannot join on memo, OLE or hyperlink object' using MS Access 2007-2013 format in a 2013 client.

I want to insert into a sharepoint list data excluding duplicates using an inner join. 
I have tried changing data types on the sharepoint list and local table with no success.

Only one field is causing the error and contains info like this "adaptor  for  98735 Line positioner to a 2ΓÇ¥ Lisrjoin actuator"

It seems like the problem is within the inner join command as it errors out when using both append and insert statements.

Here is a sample SQL statement simplified for clarity.

```
INSERT INTO assigned_stock 
            (description) 
SELECT import_assigned_stock.description 
FROM   import_assigned_stock 
       LEFT JOIN assigned_stock 
              ON import_assigned_stock.description = assigned_stock.description 
WHERE  (( ( [assigned_stock].description ) IS NULL ));
```

Is there anyway I can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to do a left join due to the Memo error or a type conversion but this SQL will insert from a .CSV file into a SharePoint list without duplicates.

```
INSERT INTO Stock ( Description, Supplier, Qty, Unit_Cost )
SELECT Stockcsv.[(Cost) Description], Stockcsv.[(Cost) Supplier], Stockcsv.[(Cost) Quantity returned to Inventory], Stockcsv.[(Cost) Cost]
FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;CharacterSet=437); DATABASE=D:\Warehouse].Stock.csv AS Stockcsv
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Stock where Stock.Supplier = Stockcsv.[(Cost) Supplier] AND Stock.Description = Stockcsv.[(Cost) Description] AND Stock.Unit_Cost = Stockcsv.[(Cost) Cost] AND Stock.Qty = Stockcsv.[(Cost) Quantity returned to Inventory]);
```

The syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO destable ( field1,field2)
SELECT filestempname.field1, filestempname.field2
FROM [Text;FMT=Delimited;HDR=YES;CharacterSet=437); DATABASE=C:\your\file\path].filename.csv AS filestempname
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM destable WHERE destable.field1 = filestempname.field1 AND destable.field2 = filestempname.field2);
```